# Where to set up MX and SPF records on sendMail or google apps mail server

Tags: sendmail, g-suite, spf, mx-record

Here is my senario:

1. I have domain say myDomain.com is using google app mail server to send and receive emails
2. I have a sendMail server deployed on my a cloudServer that I am using to send email campaigns & news letters to my clients ( with from address in head is: info@myDomain.com)
3. Now when I observe email headers of mails that I sent from my sendMail server I notice

Received-SPF: none

Some of my customers reported that campaign emails are going into spam, when I investigated  the problem I found that it can be because of "Received-SPF" is missing.

My question is Where should I setup (in cloudServer DNS OR google app mail DNS) MX, NS, CNAME records  or  or any other setting that will allow sendMail server to send email that has low risk of being marked as spam.

Answer (score 2):

First off, make sure to implement SPF-records in your dns. Your SPF-record should be something like this:

```
v=spf1 mx ip4:a.b.c.d include:aspmx.googlemail.com ~all
```

Where a.b.c.d is the IP of your sendmail-server.

To have even less chance of being marked as spam, make SendMail use the Google servers to send your email. You will need to add some AuthInfo-lines to `client-info`.

More info can be found here: [Link](http://www.linuxha.com/other/sendmail/gmail.html).

Answer (score 2):

Somewhere there is an interface that you are using to manage the DNS settings for your domain. There you need to add a TXT record for your domain which will set up the proper SPF record for it, just as Bart De Vos pointed out. So the value of the TXT record is:

`v=spf1 mx ip4:a.b.c.d include:aspmx.googlemail.com ~all`

This setup sets a proper SPF value for your domain. However, without modifying your sendmail configuration, emails that you send from your server and destined for your domain (the one hosted at Google Apps) will likely not get delivered as the server will think that it should deliver them locally and not at Google. To overcome this, [you need to follow these steps](https://serverfault.com/a/344189/25640).

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could check www.unlocktheinbox.com as they will provide the authoritative server if applicable:
http://www.unlocktheinbox.com/dnslookup/mx/unlocktheinbox.com/

They have an spf wizard that will help you to create the record if needed.

Ans one last thing, after you set up the records, you can send an email to mailtest@unlocktheinbox.com that will return your DNS setup, verify the records, provide spam score for the email, etc. This is my go to test when setting up new records. HTH!

Answer (score 0):

You should set up those records on the authoritative DNS Servers for your domain myDomain.com

Try dig command

```
dig myDomain.com
```

look at the AUTHORITY SECTION, you will see at least one NS Record
take a look at those records to guess what DNS Servers are Authoritative for your domain.