# Force sendmail to ignore local domain when sending mail (FreeBSD)

Tags: freebsd, sendmail

I send mail using PHP. Everything works good until I send mail to domain (@example.com) which I have in /etc/rc.conf >> hostname="box.example.com".

I guess sendmail catches mail for this domain (even when I use its subdomain in rc.conf) before sending it to world. So, how can I make sendmail to ignore local domain(s) other than localhost?

Comment: I guess it will be better to avoid using same hostname for server itself and domains I use for www/mail in future.

Answer (score 2):

This is a recurring question, but it is the first time I've seen it for FreeBSD. See [this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/344105/outgoing-mail-from-linux-not-being-delivered/344189#344189) on how to edit your freebsd.mc file. Because the above link answers the question for Debian, here is what you need to do in FreeBSD:

```
# cd /etc/mail
# cp freebsd.mc box.example.com.mc
# vi box.example.mc (and follow the instructions of the link above)
# make all install restart
```

You can now test the solution.

Since you write that `/etc/mail/local-host-names` does not exist, run sendmail in test mode with `sendmail -bt` and then at the `>` prompt type `$=w`. This will list you all the names that sendmail considers local.  You will see box.example.com in this list.

Comment: Only **.mc** files I have: **freebsd.mc** and **freebsd.submit.mc**, is it one of them?

Comment: I changed server hostname in /etc/rc.conf - to avoid this behaviour. It is cheaper to do/remember than reconfiguring mail server.

Comment: My (memory) mistake: freebsd.mc is what you need to copy from. I will update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Find out which file holds your local host names with `grep -i '^fw' sendmail.cf`.  Remove `example.com` from the file so named.

Comment: file /etc/mail/local-host-names does not exist

Comment: That's interesting; I'm slightly surprised sendmail starts up at all.  In that case, I defer to adamo's suggestions above (which I will now upvote).  Though you could try creating a blank `local-host-names` and see if that cures sendmail of making assumptions.

Comment: This is how it is in default FreeBSD 9.1 installation. Creating blank `local-host-names` made no change.